# does mean preserving spread require symmetric noise

Tags: stochastic-dominance

I understand the definition of **mean persevering** is as follows:

> $G$ is a *mean-preserving spread* of $F$ iff there exist random
> variables $x, y,$ and $ε$ such that $$y = x + ε,$$ $x$ is distributed
> according to F, $y$ is distributed according to G, and $E [ε|x] = 0$
> for all $x$.

The definition is Definition 4.4 in MIT OCW notes https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-123-microeconomic-theory-iii-spring-2015/lecture-notes-and-slides/MIT14_123S15_Chap4.pdf

I find most graphs(not only in the notes mentioned above but also elsewhere) illustrating the two distributions seem to draw the noise $ε$ symmetrically around $x$. Is the symmetry necessary?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you include a reference for that definition?

Comment: Definition 4.4 in the MIT notes, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-123-microeconomic-theory-iii-spring-2015/lecture-notes-and-slides/MIT14_123S15_Chap4.pdf

Comment: The example in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-preserving_spread#Example) answers your question.